# WCF 4.0 + wsHTTPBinding using F5 Load Balancer

Tags: wcf, load-balancing, wshttpbinding, f5

I have a WFP app which is connecting to a back end system through a WCF 4.0 interface using wsHttpBinding.  The WCF service is behind an F5 load balancer.

My app works in development (no F5 load balancer), but when i deploy to production, it doesn't work.  My F5 load balancer currently only has 1 real web server behind it.

This is a question which is commonly asked, but my specific detail question is the following:

**In my scenario, the connection between client and load balancer uses wsHttpBinding, but the connection between the load balancer and the web server uses basic binding.  Could this be a cause of the load balancer problem?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "basic binding". The F5 should simply redirect the request to the web service without changing the content. The only case where F5 might be a change the message is if you're using HTTPS offloading, where the client and LB talk over SSL, but the connection between the LB and the web service is HTTP or kerberos.

I suspect you've got a F5 setup problem. The way to test this would be to create a simple HTML page and publish with IIS on your web server. Then try to access that page from a browser on the client side of the load balancer. If you see the page, you know F5 redirecting the request properly. If not, you have LB setup issue.

After that, try typing the URL of the web service into a browser and see if you get the WSDL page. If you see the web page over the browser, but don't see the WSDL page, then you know you have a setup problem with your web service.

You can also set up Fiddler on your web server and check the messages coming in to see if there's a difference in the content when you connect to the web service locally versus connecting over F5.